# Javascript Creating custom scrollbars

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

What will be the best possible way to create Custom Scrollbars using Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: **don't do this**, the user is used to a certain style.  I'd be *very* surprised if you had *any* good reason for breaking this expectation.

Comment: Do you really need custom scrollbars? Are you sure that the potential improvement to the design outweighs the usability drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript DHTML » GUI Components » ScrollBar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/CustomScrollbar.htm)